# Set listview with encoded string image android

Tags: android, listview, base64, listadapter

There's someway for me to adapt a encoded string image in a `Listview`?
I got from my server, in `base64` format, a image in a string, and I want to set it in a `Listview` with some text.
Here is part of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < makers.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = makers.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable

    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String age = c.getString(TAG_AGE);
    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
    String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
    String disc = c.getString(TAG_DISC);
    Long date = c.getLong(TAG_DATE);
    String num = c.getString(TAG_NUM);

    // creating new HashMap
    //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    String image=c.getString(TAG_IMAGE1);
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
    map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
    map.put(TAG_AGE, age);
    map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);
    map.put(TAG_DISC, disc);
    map.put(TAG_NUM, num);
    map.put(TAG_IMAGE1, bitmap);
    // map.put(TAG_CIDADE, cidade);
    long curdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long onem =  curdate - date;
    long intm = 3*30*24*60*60*1000 ;
    if(onem >= intm){

    } else {
       // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        userdataList.add((HashMap<String, String>) map);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my Adapter:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting the related idioms
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListResult1.this, userdataList,
                        R.layout.list_view, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_USERNAME, TAG_AGE, TAG_RATING, TAG_DISC, TAG_NUM, TAG_IMAGE1},
                        new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.username, R.id.age, R.id.rating, R.id.disc, R.id.num, R.id.ivimage1s});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
```

And i want also to transfer that image through a intent, it's possible?
The actual problem is that I can't set a adapter for my image, all the text part work just fine, but the image did not loaded.
Sorry for any English issue, it's not my mother language.

Comment: it has a hello guys before all that :(

Comment: the best way to show images along with text is using grid view. i have a working code in which i have shown images along with their names in a grid view.whereas  in list view screen space is not fully occupied and empty spaces are wasted due to which user suffers a lot of scrolling.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are facing ?

Comment: You are not clear at all please specify the issue.

Comment: I can see you have written code for converting Base 64 string to image byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); Set this bitmap on imageview object and to pass this bitmap to other activity through intent use  intent.putExtra("pic", bitmap); and to get in receiving activity  Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("pic");

Comment: the actual problem is that I can't set a adapter for my image, all the text part work just fine, but the image did not loaded

Comment: @Dharmitabhatt does exist something like .getImage??? Because before I was using .getText to do the intent stuff.I was getting the position of the selected item and then transferring through the intent

Comment: You can get bitmap  from imageview object, Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: thanks man @Dharmitabhatt, happy new year for u and ur famile

Comment: Same to you:) hope that helped